# Hotmail login on azure asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, hotmail

I'm developing ASP.NET web application that will run on Windows Azure.
In my local enviroment http address of application is 127.0.0.1:81.

I want to use possibility of logging for user with hotmail account.
To do that I had to register my application domain to be with hotmail services(be it www.application.com).

To do development hotmail docs suggest to bind domain address to my development machine local host address.(via altering hosts file and putting line 127.0.0.1 www.application.com), that way each time on my machine it is referenced domain address of my application it gets redirected to localhost.

The problem I'm facing is that Azure by default uses port 81 so the localhost address of my application is 127.0.0.1:81 and when I set IIS server to listen by default to that port,
Azure changes that port. So two applications had to work on one port Azure local development enviroment and IIS.

Can any one point me to the solution ?

Regards
Wojciech

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using the [Access Control Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg429786.aspx) for Identity Federation? 
This should allow you to use live-id to authentication to your application
If not - take a look at [Using Access Control Service for Identity Federation](http://yossidahan.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/using-access-control-service-for-identity-federation/) and [End-to-end authentication and authorisation scenario for MVC+ACS](http://yossidahan.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/end-to-end-authentication-and-authorisation-scenario-for-mvcacs/)

I know that additional capabilities had been added and It's been a while since I looked at this (will probably spend some time on it again in a couple of weeks), but hopefully not too much had changed with the existing capabilities as described.